# Getting too many positional arguments error

Tags: flutter, dart

How does positional arguments work?

```
children: <Widget>[
  Table(
    children: [
      _buildTableRow(
        'one',
        'two',
        'Three'
      ),
    ],
  ),
],
```

I'm getting an error saying `_buildTableRow` has too many positional arguments.

```
TableRow _buildTableRow(String listOfNames) {
  return TableRow(
    children: listOfNames.split(',').map((name) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(name)),
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_buildTableRow(String listOfNames)
```

only accept one string 
and in your code 
you pass three strings

```
_buildTableRow(
    'one',
    'two',
    'Three'
  ),
```

you can do this

```
  _buildTableRow("one, two, Three")
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BasicTable(),
    );
  }
}


class BasicTable extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Table Widget")),
      body: Table(
        defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(150.0),
        border: TableBorder(
          horizontalInside: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black,
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
            width: 1.0,
          ),
          verticalInside: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black,
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
            width: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
        children: [
          _buildTableRow("one, two, three"),
          _buildTableRow("Inducesmile.com, Google.com, Flutter.dev"),
          _buildTableRow("Inducesmile.com, Google.com, Flutter.dev"),
          _buildTableRow("Inducesmile.com, Google.com, Flutter.dev"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TableRow _buildTableRow(String listOfNames) {
    return TableRow(
      children: listOfNames.split(',').map((name) {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
TableRow _buildTableRow(String listOfNames) {
  return TableRow(
    children: listOfNames.split(',').map((name) {
      return Container(child: Text(name));
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

And use it like:

```
_buildTableRow('one,two,Three')
```

Comment: Hi CopsOnRoad. Regarding [your edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58353450/revisions), could I ask you to leave attribution messages in CW answers? It's been discussed on Meta and in SO CVR. I think the consensus is that the licensing conditions are only satisfied if it is made clear who wrote the content. I can dig a link out for you if you want to read.

Comment: @halfer Hi, the same answer was already provided by another user (diegoveloper), and you mentioned "Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question" however OP updated his post (after that user wrote in comment how to solve it), after OP updated post, that user wrote it as answer. Hope I was able to clear that point.

Comment: Your description above isn't particularly clear, but after reading a few times, I think I know what you mean - the original authorship was from diegoveloper and not BloodLoss (OP) and thus it did not need attribution. I am not sure I agree, but the correct course of action here would be to leave the post unedited, and ask for it to be deleted. (Perhaps you did ask for it to be deleted, since a moderator deleted it).

Comment: Ultimately, my main point is that where you see attribution added deliberately, it is best not to remove it. [Here is a relevant discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356951/if-i-repost-an-answer-merged-into-a-question-do-i-need-to-note-the-attribution) on Meta.

Comment: @halfer Yes you got my point (even when I read it now, I didn't get that clearly in first attempt lol), and sorry I didn't know about `attribution` before.

Comment: No worries. See also [the license](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), which mentions attribution specifically.